# What is the SQL in pgAdmin for PostgGIS Shapefile loader GUI Import and Export

Tags: shapefile, postgresql-10, postgis-2.4

I have been using PostGIS Shapefile loader to import and export shapefile, but now I want to ask is there any SQL alternative to this GUI import and export.

Comment: the *Importer* is a GUI for the command line tool *shp2pgsql* that comes shipped with your *PostGIS* installation, and you can use that directly (or e.g. *ogr2ogr*) via terminal. ...you could try and convert the *.dbf* files to *.csv* and import those with`COPY`...but that's just a dirty hack.

Comment: To get geometries into SQL you'll need to create WKT Strings. All solutions i can think of will be using a converter, you can't directly import a shapefile like you can with csv files for example.

Answer (score 2):

### QGIS DB manager

To import a shapefile into PostGIS I prefer to use the DB Manager in QGIS. It can be used to import or export GIS files like shapefiles into/from spatial databases like PostGIS, SpatiaLite,...

A manual with the explanation on how to import a shapefile into PostGIS with QGIS DB manager can be found on: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/databases/db_manager.html#importing-data-into-a-database-with-db-manager

### ogr2ogr

If you want to use a command line tool to import shapefiles into PostGIS you can use ogr2ogr. More information about that tool can be found on https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html and on https://www.bostongis.com/?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet#41.